# What is the difference between image mean subtraction and pixel mean subtraction?

Tags: neural-network, caffe, conv-neural-network, image-segmentation

I know that we need to center our input data in order to facilitate the NN training with a global scalar learning rate. But what difference does subtracting the pixel mean across all channels (R, G, B) make instead of the image mean?

Moreover, it makes more sense to me to use the image mean as different spatial regions of the images in our training network might have different means, and subtracting a constant pixel mean calculated across the complete image will rather not centre the input properly.

P.S. I'm working on a image segmentation problem, so if the context affects the answer, please point it out.

Answer (score 4):

Just to clarify Mean Image vs Mean Pixel:

Image - Mean image per channel (e.g. For 250 X 250 image having 3 channels, we have 3 mean images of dimensions 250 X 250 with mean values across the pixel positions)

Pixel - Single mean value per channel ((E.g. Red channel mean, Green Channel Mean, Blue Channel Mean)

**As per me Mean image is good to use at the time of inference, when we are unsure about how model was trained actually (With w/o batch norm or mean).**

Answer (score 0):

You should take mean across each channel (R,G,B) to zero-center images properly.